# HTTP Request in Mule 4

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

```
<http:request path="${generalPath}" method="GET" doc:name="Test GET method" config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration">
            <http:query-params ><![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
    "getVal" : "number=#[vars.id]"
}]]]></http:query-params>
            <http:request-builder>
                <http:query-param paramName="getVal" value="number=#[vars.id]"/>

            </http:request-builder>
        </http:request>
```

Hi! I was trying to use HTTP Request in Mule 4 with query param name= "getVal" and value = "number=#[vars.id]". But it got error. The error said that "Required attribute key is not defined in query param" but I did add the name and value in query parameters. Please help! :'(

Answer (score 0):

As the query params are already a DW expression, you don't need to insert a new DW interpreter context (#[ ]) when accessing the vars context.

Also, when the right side of the assignment statement is enclosed between double quotes, it's being interpreted as a String, and not as an expression to access the id variable. To do so, you need to enclose only "number=" in double quotes, and concatenate the value of vars.id.

Try using the following DW expression:

```
output application/java
---
{
    "getVal": "number=" ++ vars.id
}
```